# How can I show ack results and occurrence count

Tags: linux, ack

```
ack foo *
```

returns a listing of lines:

```
bar.txt
28: this is foo stuff

dump.txt
12: results of foo

gobs.txt
1137: more lines with foo
```

and

```
ack -c -l
```

returns

```
3
```

My question is, how can I show both? I'd like the list of lines as in the first example *and* a count of the number of lines that matched as in the second example.

Comment: You can't.  And, in ack 2.0, it will explicitly tell you "You can't use -c and -l together".

Comment: Ack 2.12 lets me use -c and -l together. It displays a list of the names of matched files and the number of matches in each file. As far as I can see, you still can't do what OP is trying to do though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use

`ack -hc` (`-h` being shorthand for `--no-filename`) to get a total count.

According to [the ack documentation/man page](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.14-man.html):

> #### -c, --count
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file. If `-l` is in effect, it will only show the number of lines for each file that has lines matching. Without `-l`, some line counts may be zeroes.
>
> If combined with `-h` (`--no-filename`) `ack` outputs only one total count.

Here's what worked for me (expanding on @Jordan's answer) --

`ack 'pattern' && ack -hc 'pattern'`

or, better (IMO):

`ack 'pattern'; ack -hc 'pattern'`

As far as I understand, using `&&`, the second command depends on the first one returning to run; using `;` instead will just run them both, one after the other, regardless.  In this case, I think the `;` is more appropriate.

Comment: Great answer, I was looking for this for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to get `ack` to output both of the things you want in a single command. The easiest way to get what you want is to chain both commands together with `&&`.